# How to bind to a specified element of an array to image source in LongListSelector in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a model Article. Article has a property `ImagePath`, and `ImagePath` is array of `Uri string`.

In a specified page. I just want to show the first Image of the ImagePath list. So I do it like below and no image displays.

```
 <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath.[0]}" Height="50" Width="50" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,7,7,0"
                           Grid.RowSpan="2">
```

Other properties display well, anyone can help me on this?

Model is as follow:

```
public class Article
{
    public List<string> ImagePath = new List<string>();
    public string Subject;
    public string Words;
}
```

and i have image control in a longlistselector in my xaml

```
<phone:LongListSelector 
                    x:Name="articleList"
                    Grid.Row="1"   
                    Margin="0,0,-12,0" 
                    DataContext="{StaticResource viewModel}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResultItemTemplate}"   
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ArticleCollection}"
                    ItemRealized="articleList_ItemRealized"
                    SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged"

                    >

                </phone:LongListSelector>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ResultItemTemplate">
            <Grid Margin="0,6,0,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Height="50" Width="50" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,7,7,0"
                       Grid.RowSpan="2">

                </Rectangle>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath.[0]}" Height="50" Width="50" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,7,7,0"
                       Grid.RowSpan="2">

                </Image>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Subject, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                 Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Words, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                               VerticalAlignment="Top"
                               />

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Not sure there should be a . in there! Try ImagePath[0]. But my suggestion would be to add an extra property on the Article class - ImageToDisplay and that would return the first image in the list. So that you can use that property in your XAML binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using BitmapImage or WriteableBitmap as Another property

```
public List<String> ImagePath = new List<String>();
public BitmapImage SelectedImage;
```

And use it like this.

```
Article ArticleCollection = new Article();
ArticleCollection.BitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ArticleCollection.Imagepath[0]));

articleList.ItemsSource = ArticleCollection;
```

Comment: I do it as u wrote here, and i got binding exception. 

BindingExpression path error: 'BitImage' property not found on 'CollectionApp.Models.Article' 'CollectionApp.Models.Article' (HashCode=60828848). BindingExpression: Path='BitImage'

the xaml is:

<Image Source="{Binding BitImage}" Height="50" Width="50" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,7,7,0"
                           Grid.RowSpan="2">

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help you, I had same problem and bind BitmapImage as Image source solves my problem.

**Your model class**

```
  public class Article
            {
                public List<string> ImagePath = new List<string>();
                public string Subject;
                public string Words;
                BitmapImage _image;
                public BitmapImage BindImage
                {
                   **Edits**
                    get{
                        return _image ;
                       }
                    set
                    {
                        if (ImagePath.Any())
                           {
                            value = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImagePath.FirstOrDefault(), UriKind.Relative));
                         _image = value;
                           }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Your xaml should be**

```
<Image Source="{Binding BindImage}" Height="50" Width="50" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,7,7,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
```

Comment: got compile error;  Error 1 'CollectionApp.Models.Article.BitImage.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial C:\Users\heyun\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CollectionApp\CollectionApp\Models\Article.cs 85 13 CollectionApp

Comment: @max i mdse change in my ans, Please give a look.

Comment: Image Source cannot bind to BitmapImage? i make the uri a string and bind to Image Source, it works.  when a BitmapImage type, it fails....

Answer (score 1):

I would follow @Depechie comment and use special property for this. I would also extend your `Article` class a little to notify UI when there is a chance that `ImagePath[0]` might have changed. I think it could look like this:

```
public class Article : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<string> ImagePath = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private string subject;
    public string Subject
    {
       get { return subject; }
       set { subject = value; RaiseProperty("Subject"); }
    }
    private string words;
    public string Words
    {
       get { return words; }
       set { words = value; RaiseProperty("Words"); }
    }
    public Article()
    {
       ImagePath.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => { RaiseProperty("FirstImage"); };
    }

    // public Uri FirstImage // this can work if your image is a content of your App
    // {
    //    get
    //    {
    //         return new Uri(ImagePath.FirstOrDefault(), UriKind.Relative);
    //    }
    // }

   public BitmapImage FirstImage // getter - BitmapImage
   {
        get
        {
           if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ImagePath[0])) return null;
           BitmapImage temp = new BitmapImage();

           using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
           using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = ISF.OpenFile(ImagePath[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                temp.SetSource(file);
           return temp;
        }
    }


    public void RaiseProperty(string property = null)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

As you can see I've changed your `List` to `ObservableCollection`, and thus I'm able to subscribe in constructor to `CollectionChanged` event. So when the `ImagePath` changes, `PropertyChanged` is raised and your `Image` can be updated.

I've also created mentioned property `FirstImage` with `get` accessor, so that your `Image` can get Uri from it. Usage:

```
<Image Source="{Binding FirstImage}" Height="50" Width="50" Grid.Row="0" 
       Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,7,7,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
```

I've also made your `Subject` and `Words` properties and added them a chance to update UI when they have changed.

**And last but maybe the most important thing** - getting an image depends on where it is - if it was downloaded and is an `IsolatedStorageFile` or it is a build in content. I've edited my answer to set it from IsolatedStorage, as I suspect, that you have your images there. If they are a build in content then uncomment lines above.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.. this is the code snippet

```
// your model class
public class Article
{
         public WiteableBitmap[] ImagePath { get; set; }
public string Subject { get; set; }
public string Words { get; set; }
}


//your xaml
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath[0]}".../>

//your cs
WriteableBitmap writeableBitMap;
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(yourimageuri);
bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
bmp.ImageOpened += (sender, event) =>
{

    writeableBitMap = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)sender);
};

Article ArticleCollection = new Article();
ArticleCollection.ImagePath = new WriteableBitmap[yourarraysize];
ArticleCollection.ImagePath[0] = writeableBitMap;

articleList.ItemsSource = ArticleCollection;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the Binding of `Source` property of the `Image`. Try by removing the dot:

```xaml
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath[0]}" Height="50" Width="50" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,7,7,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT here to come a conclusion of this question

First of all, i need to say "Thank you so much for those guys who answer my question"

1. add an extra property is the right answer here, i did as suggestions
2. why a BitmapImage contains web url bind to Image source does not work, i will ask in another thread.
3. why ImagePath[0] does not work according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx. i will also ask in another thread.